# How to solve npm install throwing fsevents warning on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

```
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

What if i uninstall fsevents ? even though it doesnt support my machine.
And how can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

fsevents is not supported on windows machines.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents

> I'm getting EBADPLATFORM Unsupported platform for fsevents error.

> It's fine, nothing is broken. fsevents is macos-only. Other platforms are skipped. If you want to hide this warning, report a bug to NPM bugtracker asking them to hide ebadplatform warnings by default.

/edit:

To adress your concern: All functionality regarding fsevents will not work, but this will also not break your code, unless it relies purely on fsevents. For example, webpack still works just fine without fsevents, you just have to restart it instead of having hotloading when `npm run dev`

Comment: it always displayed in terminal everytime i run ``` yarn install ```  also ``` yarn add <package> ``` still